# Can I run an SQLite operation from Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, sqlite

When I download transactions in Quicken Essentials for Mac, my bank adds "DEBIT PURCHASE" and other junk to the Payee info.

Quicken has no ability to find and replace globally.

But I dug into the Quicken data file and it turns out all the transactions are stored in a SQLite file.

I was able to open this file with [Liya](http://cutedgesystems.com/software/liya/) and then run a query, e.g.,

`UPDATE ZFIPAYEE SET ZNAME = replace(ZNAME,'DEBIT PURCHASE - ','');`

which cleaned up my transactions.

Is there some way I can run this kind of query directly from Terminal without having to open up Liya and then opening the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `/usr/bin/sqlite3` command line tool to modify the database. It ships, default, with OS X so you don't need to do anything other than open a Terminal window and then run:

```
cd path/to/quicken/storage/directory
sqlite3 <quicken database file>

SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> UPDATE ZFIPAYEE SET ZNAME = replace(ZNAME,'DEBIT PURCHASE - ','');
sqlite> .quit
```

You can do it all from one command line like this if you like:

```
sqlite3 <quicken database file> 'UPDATE ZFIPAYEE SET ZNAME = replace(ZNAME,\'DEBIT PURCHASE - \',\'\');'
```

That will open, modify and close your database file and return the prompt.

For more information on using the SQLite command line too see: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: Awesome! Now ... is there a way to `replace` with wildcards? I also want to delete all the `CHECKCARD 1215` references, where the `1215` is a date that changes all the time. Does `replace` have a wildcard function?

Comment: ...or maybe I could just 'trim' off the first 14 characters where `like "CHECKCARD ____%"` ?

Comment: SQLite supports just about the whole gamut of SQL queries, so yes you can use wildcards with `replace`. You're venturing in to a topic that's slightly out of bounds for Ask Different though because it's not Apple-specific. It's actually a programming question.

Comment: Which StackExchange site do you suggest? I Googled wildcards for `replace` and came up with nothing easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ -- don't quote me a wildcards and `replace` though. I am far from an SQL expert.